# Entity Framework: How to enable cascade delete on one way related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

There are Two Entities such as bellow:

```
public class Business
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public File Logo {get; set;}
    public int? LogoId {get; set;}

    public File Video {get; set;}
    public int? Video {get; set;}

    public ICollection<File> Images {get; set;}
}

public class File
{
    // some file props, such as Id, Name, ...
}
```

How can I configure cascade delete for files on business delete?
Please consider that I don't need any navigation from `File` to `Business`.

UPDATE:

You may find the modelBuilder configuration as bellow:

```
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.Business>()
            .HasOptional(b => b.Logo)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.Business>()
            .HasOptional(b => b.Video)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Entities.Business>()
            .HasMany(b => b.Images)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

and here is the error I've got:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Files_dbo.Businesses_Business_Id1' on table 'Files' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not
>   create constraint

Comment: Code First? Model First? Database First?

Comment: I'm trying code first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you like to use seperate configuration classes you could try something like that:

```
  public class BusinessConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Business>
  {
        public BusinessConfiguration()
        {
            HasMany(x => x.Images).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete();
            HasOptional(x => x.Logo).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete();
            HasOptional(x => x.Video).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete();
        }
  }
```

When you do not pass a lambda within `.WithOptional()` or `.WithRequired()` means the other side has no navigation properties.

Comment: oops! Got following error:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Files_dbo.Businesses_Business_Id1' on table 'Files' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.